# How to download a list of URLs without using wget, only depth 1 (do not follow links) on Windows

Tags: windows-10, download

On Windows 10, I am looking for software (or another way) to download a list of URLs, but only the initial page. For example say the landing page for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) was index.html, do not follow any links on the page, only download [www.example.com/index.html](http://www.example.com/index.html). The solution must be completely free and not involve using wget.

Comment: strange restrictions... can you use curl instead?

Comment: PowerShell has this ability e.g. `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri example.com -OutFile C:/some/path.html`. You can loop through the URLs in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

You can use curl:

curl -o sitename.html https://www.example.com